# react-native-video fit to my fixed width height of an item of a flatlist

Tags: react-native, react-native-flatlist, react-native-video, react-native-vision-camera

I have a flatList that render video and photo of when i use resizemode to cover it cover the space but cut some portion of the video and if use resizemode to contain then it will not fit the screen width but fit the height,my used code of the video container get no fixed width or height but the video style is

```
width: "100%",
        height: height * 0.4,
        backgroundColor:"#faf8fd"
```

my code

```
 <View>
                         <Video source={{ uri: newVideourl }}
                                ref={player}
                                poster= {thumbImagee}
                                posterResizeMode='contain'
                                onBuffer={onBuffer}
                                onError={onError}
                                resizeMode="contain"
                                paused={isPlaying}
                                repeat
                                muted={isMuted}
                                onLoadStart={() => {
                                    setVideoLoadOpacity(1);
                                }}
                                onLoad={() => {
                                    setVideoLoadOpacity(0);
                                }}
                                style={styles.backgroundVideo} />
```

```
 backgroundVideo: {
        width: "100%",
        height: height * 0.4,
        backgroundColor:"#faf8fd"
    },
```